# What is the proper way of enabling Stream Management in smack 4.1.1

Tags: xmpp, smack, stream-management

I have search every for the method used in enabling stream management in smack and nothing is working for me

This function isSmAvailable() always return false, am using prosody as the XMPP server in which the smacks[mod_smacks] is installed and enabled below is my code

```
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder configureBuilder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
configureBuilder.setServiceName(Config.XMPP_HOST);
configureBuilder.setHost(HOST);
//configureBuilder.allowEmptyOrNullUsernames();
configureBuilder.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);


    //configureBuilder.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
    SmackConfiguration.DEBUG = true;
    xmppConnection = new XMPPTCPConnection(configureBuilder.build());
    Roster.setDefaultSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.accept_all);




    XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementResumptiodDefault(true);
    //PingManager
    xmppConnection.setUseStreamManagement(true);
    xmppConnection.setUseStreamManagementResumption(true);

    ReconnectionManager reconnectionManager = ReconnectionManager.getInstanceFor(xmppConnection);
    reconnectionManager.enableAutomaticReconnection();


    try {
      MyLog.w("Connecting to xmpp server");
       xmppConnection.setPacketReplyTimeout(100000);
       xmppConnection.connect();
       //xmppConnection.sendSmAcknowledgement();


       if (xmppConnection.isSmEnabled()) {
      MyLog.w("stream M is enabled");
       } else {
      MyLog.w("stream M is not enabled");
       }


       if (xmppConnection.isSmAvailable()) {
      MyLog.w("stream M available");
       } else {
      MyLog.w("stream M is not available");
       }

       //xmppConnection.
       xmppConnection.addConnectionListener(new ConnectionListener() {
       @Override
       public void connected(XMPPConnection xmppConnection) {
       //logger.warning("Connected to server successfully");
       MyLog.w("Connected to server");
       }

       @Override
       public void authenticated(XMPPConnection xmppConnect, boolean b) {
       //logger.warning("Nice it is authenticated too");
       MyLog.w("Finally logged into the server");

       }

       @Override
       public void connectionClosed() {
       //logger.warning("Connected to server failed");
       }

       @Override
       public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception e) {
       //logger.warning(e.getMessage());
       MyLog.w("Connection close on error" + e.getMessage());
       }

       @Override
       public void reconnectionSuccessful() {
       //I think here we need to relogin the user
       MyLog.w("Reconnected successfully ....thanks to RC");
       }

       @Override
       public void reconnectingIn(int i) {

      }

       @Override
       public void reconnectionFailed(Exception e) {
      MyLog.w("Reconnection Failed " + e.getMessage());
       }
      });
    } catch (Exception e) {
      MyLog.w("connected-error" + e.getMessage());
    }
```

I tried adding streamFeature for stream management using

xmppConnection.addStreamFeature() but it tells me that the function is private

and also through ProviderManager.addStreamFeature(element, namespace, provider) is also not working

Can you please help me to figure this out or there is something am doing wrong here

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable stream management xmpp connection smack 4.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31330991/enable-stream-management-xmpp-connection-smack-4-1)

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code is working for me having ejabbered on server side--

```
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration connConfig = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                                            .setHost(HOST)
                                            .setPort(PORT)
                                            .setDebuggerEnabled(true)
                                            .setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled)
                                            .setUsernameAndPassword(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
                                            .setServiceName(SERVICE).build();

XMPPTCPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(connConfig);

connection.setUseStreamManagement(true);
connection.setPacketReplyTimeout(TIME_OUT);
connection.connect();
connection.login();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your ejabbered config file for stream management is enable or not.

```
stream_management: true
resend_on_timeout: true
resume_timeout: 300
```

In android code you just add to below line to enable stream management in your app.

```
 static{
    XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementDefault(true);
    XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementResumptionDefault(true);
}
```