# Enable stream management xmpp connection smack 4.1

Tags: xmpp, smack, stream-management

I tried enabling stream management(XEP-0198) by this piece of code

```
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration connConfig = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder().setHost(HOST)
            .setPort(PORT).setDebuggerEnabled(true).setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled)
            .setUsernameAndPassword(USERNAME, PASSWORD).setServiceName(SERVICE).build();

    XMPPTCPConnectionconnection = new XMPPTCPConnection(connConfig);

        connection.setPacketReplyTimeout(TIME_OUT);
        connection.connect();
        connection.login();
        connection.setUseStreamManagement(true);
```

But later when I check for stream management it returns false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you need to set stream management before connecting to xmpp.

```
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration connConfig = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder().setHost(HOST)
        .setPort(PORT).setDebuggerEnabled(true).setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled)
        .setUsernameAndPassword(USERNAME, PASSWORD).setServiceName(SERVICE).build();

XMPPTCPConnectionconnection = new XMPPTCPConnection(connConfig);

    connection.setUseStreamManagement(true);
    connection.setPacketReplyTimeout(TIME_OUT);
    connection.connect();
    connection.login();
```

Comment: can you look at this question- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31331329/not-able-to-get-lastactivity-of-a-jabberid